# Add icons next to field labels in salesforce

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

Is there a way that we can add icons next to field labels whenever we are creating or editing Opportunity record. I know one way is to add inline Visualforce Page to the page layout but is there any standard way to accomplish this?

Comment: I believe you can try a custom wrapper class

Comment: Yea, again that involves using vf page only and dragging that vf page into every page layout and having this logic in controller class. But I am not looking for any custom code. Is there any standard way to do the same?

Comment: It's not possible through out of box functionality